# XmlReader Innertext Problem

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have an Xml document in which some of the elements look like this:

```
<rootNode attib1="qwerty" >
<subNode1>W</subNode1>
<subNode2>X</subNode2>
<subNode3>Y</subNode3>
<subNode4>Z</subNode4>
ABC
</rootNode>
```

My objective is to get "ABC" out of the above example. I tried looking at the InnerText (which returns "WXYZABC") and InnerXml and Value (which returns null) properties in the XmlElement class and bunch of properties in the XmlReader class too. Somehow I don't see an elegant way to extract the data I need.

Can someone please help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't rootNode element have an additional XmlElement of type XmlTextNode with value ABC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the excellent suggestion from @djechelon, I seem to have found a solution to this:

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        xdoc.Load(@"D:\Test.xml");
        XmlElement xmlElement = xdoc.DocumentElement;
        foreach (XmlNode node in xmlElement.ChildNodes)
            if (node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text
                && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(node.Value))
                Console.WriteLine(node.Value.Trim());
```

The above uses the simple fact that the inner text is also an XmlNode as part of the ChildNodes collection of the XmlElement.

Thanks everyone for the great responses!

Answer (score 3):

Have a go with this one:

```
string xml = @"<rootNode attib1=""qwerty"" >
    <subNode1>W</subNode1>
    <subNode2>X</subNode2>
    <subNode3>Y</subNode3>
    <subNode4>Z</subNode4>
    ABC
</rootNode>";

var xElement = XElement.Parse(xml);
xElement.Elements().Remove();
xElement.Value.Dump();
```

What it does is remove all the known Elements and that leaves you with the text you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try `XmlElement.Value`

Edit:  This is the wrong approach as this will always return NULL on an element node.

Comment: @Keith, `XmlElement.Value` always returns `null`. Also, questioner says he already tried that :)

Comment: XmlElement.Value returns non-null values only when the element is a leaf node AFAIK.

Comment: @Chetan, nope, always `null`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.value.aspx.

Comment: Yep, and I'm surprised that's what it returns.  Seems like the "right" way to pull what @Chetan is looking for, however the documentation says differently.  Though I must admit:  my recommendation would be to not form my XML in this manner anyway :)

Comment: @Keith Of course. Unfortunately, this form of Xml is sometimes spit out by the runtime while capturing WCF traces. I'm currently in the process of writing a "scrubbing tool" to fix such errors.

@Frédéric Thank you for the MSDN link. I stand corrected.

Regards.

Comment: @Chetan - The thing is, with XSLT, xsl:value-of will return what you're looking for.  Have you tried using XPath as an alternative?

Comment: @djechelon, @Keith and @Frédéric: I will try out your recommendations and get back to you.